# Is there a "multimedia comments" add-in for Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-addins

I mean, an add-in that allows me to associate image and sound files with a comment in the middle of the code. Does this exist already?

That would be great to help people to understand other's code. As the wise said: An image is worth a thousand words...

Comment: I can't see an advantage of images and especially not sound files, but, if you really want them, use hyperlinks as Gerrie Schenck suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of this, but the code window has support for hyperlinks. You can click them when holding the Ctrl key to follow a link.

You might use this to link to images or videos hosted on your network...

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you show us how to create a link to a file in the code window?

Comment: well, just write: http: //www.example.com/example (without the space after http:, stack overflow changes the text it if i remove that space)

Comment: like dbemerlin said... the link will appear underlined in the comment. When you hover over it VS will tell you that Ctrl + click will follow the link.

Comment: It isn't exactly what I was looking for but in fact solves the problem. Thanks.